# Regarding stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm new to stored procedure. I want to assign the values returned from SELECT statement into a variable. The datatype of the returned values is Numeric(18,3) and there are about 200 rows as output. Is it possible to assign all those values in the variable ? If not what should be done do make use of those values?

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE SMSBRegisCharge

@balance numeric(18,3)
AS

@balance = Select (dbo.GetAvailBalAmt(acc, 0)/100) from SMSCIF 
           where (dbo.GetAvailBalAmt(acc,0)/100) > 100;
```

Expected output.

```
14909.7000000
103203.4100000
3826.8700000
131222.6000000
198.9900000
4726.7800000
514423.8000000
542.7600000
16529.1000000
379.8100000
41442.7200000
337072.2700000
39056.4700000
199620.2100000
```

Comment: You can return a table variable, or you can just return the result as a result set the same way that a select statement does. If you want to concatenate them all into a single string you can do that too, but I think you should look at other options.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to specify your particular technical issue.

Comment: @Trincula . . . Tag your question with the database you are using (presumably SQL Server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the syntax in the question, I assume you are using SQL Server.

You can assign a *single* value directly in the `SELECT`:

```
select @balance = dbo.GetAvailBalAmt(acc, 0) / 100
from SMSCIF
where (dbo.GetAvailBalAmt(acc,0)/100) > 100;
```

You can use a subquery with `set` as well:

```
set @balance = (Select @balance = dbo.GetAvailBalAmt(acc, 0) / 100
                from SMSCIF
                where (dbo.GetAvailBalAmt(acc,0)/100) > 100
               );
```

However, you cannot assign multiple values to a variable.  You can create a temporary table or table variable:

declare @balances table (balance int);  -- or whatever the type is:

```
insert into @balances (balance)
    select dbo.GetAvailBalAmt(acc, 0) / 100
    from SMSCIF
    where (dbo.GetAvailBalAmt(acc,0)/100) > 100;
```